# Jmeter - добавить данные в тело запроса из файла

Tags: jmeter

Всем привет! Есть такая проблема. Мне нужно выполнить апи-запрос в теле которого содержится огромная строка (имедж в формате Base64 и размером до 2 Мб). Вопрос в том, что я не знаю как из файла (текстового), в котором содержится эти данные картинки вычитать и присвоить какой-нить переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Функция [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)

[image: JMeter FileToString]

Ее можно использовать прямо в теле запроса или, если вы планируете обращаться к содержимому файла > 1 раза - лучше инициализировать один раз где-нибудь в [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables)

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!!!

Comment: Dmitri T, мне хотелось бы лично с Вами пообщаться по jmeter - есть пул вопросов по нему